# How to format the date retrieved from the database

Tags: android, datetime, date-formatting, sqldatetime

I retrieved date time from the database and kept it into a `ArrayList<String>` type variable. Now I want to format this string.So I need to make a date object firstly. But some problems occurred when I making date object. Following is my code.

```
Date date = new Date(bookingTime.get(i));
```

Here `bookingTime` is the `ArrayList`. Can anyone suggest me what is wrong..

Comment: can you provide a example date value that you are receiving from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer...

```
String date = "2014-11-25 14:30";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM");
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use SimpleDateFormat class

**Update**

```
try {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
       String myDate = "2015-12-09 15:36:00";
       Date date = format.parse(myDate);
} 
catch (ParseException e) { 
   e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

this will do the trick. :)

Comment: my datetime formate is 2015-12-09 15:36:00 and I applied your suggestion it's give null output.Can you explain

Answer (score 0):

First check your date which is you are getting from database  after that you can make formatted date according to your database date structure.

Comment: my database date is like 2015-12-09 15:36:00

Comment: @opu may i know in which format you want to conver this date

Comment: String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm:ss a").format(date); use this format .if you got your answer then link my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new Date(bookingTime.get(i));
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);
```

Other formatting available standard are,

```
"yyyy-MM-dd"
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ"
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use belo lines of code for it:-

```
  String dtStart = "11/08/2013 08:48:10";
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  try {
    date = format.parse(dtStart); //// Here dtStart is yours bookingTime.get(i)
    System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: my bookingTime.get(i) is string but date data type is long so It's making error.my date time formate is 2015-12-09 15:36:00

Comment: @opuopu ... Did u resolve your problem ?? Or want some help ??

Comment: I couldn't. I think your answer concept is right but Date date = new Date(bookingTime.get(i)); line makes error

Comment: Date date = new Date("21-12-2015");
        String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd a").format(date);                                                           Are you getting the value like that "21-12-2015" in the bookingTime.get(i) string??

Comment: I am getting 2015-11-23 18:39:00 this value from the bookingTime.get(i) and when I write Date date = new Date(bookingTime.get(i)); it shows error

Comment: Date gettedDate = new Date("2015-11-23 18:39:00"); this is the problem actually

Comment: why are you taking the time along with the date

Comment: You can also use these function like (bookingTime.get(i).substring(0, 10))  to use only date in it...@opuopu ...Why did u accept that answer if it is not workable for you??

Comment: Actually, its come from database and the database was datetime formate. and now I want to format it into android.I was concerned with the concept that's why. Now can you suggest me what to do

Comment: Firstly you have to separate the date and time from the "bookingTime.get(i)"......By using the subSring method...as i committed above...

Comment: If it is workable for you than plz mark answer as right for other people...who may also will stuck in the same problem

Comment: @opuopu ...what is the difference between my answer and yours ACCEPTED answer....its not fair...you firstly accepted my answer and yesterday you accepted my copied answer of "Akash bhatt -Aks4125-" ....Its not fair bro